# Someone could help me to find mistakes in this codes C programming

Tags: c

I try to solve a questions in a Exercise in C language programming but i dont know if my point of view about the mistakes in this codes are right.

The exercise say : What is wrong in this code.
1)

```
void main()
{
 int variable = 0x1;
 int *puntero = &variable;
{
    int ch = 0x10;
    puntero = &ch;
 }    
 printf("%x\n", *puntero);
 }
```

In the first code I thinking that is bad the part that say 'int *ptr = &var;' becouse its not valid to put *ptr=&var.

```
  #define Tam_buffer 10

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   char buffer[Tam_buffer];
   strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
   printf("buffer= %s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
   }
```

In the second one I dont have idea where is the miskate maybe because in the main function there are int main(int argc, char *argv[])?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, unlikely to get an answer when phrased like this. Better to make friends in your course, then chat with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The { and } create a local scope where the value `int ch` belongs.

```
{
    int ch = 0x10;
    puntero = &ch;
 }    
 printf("%x\n", *puntero);
```

So in the first function the final vlaue of `puntero` points to a variable that is no longer in scope. This is undefined behavior.

In the second, you have a possible buffer overflow calling strcpy.

```
char buffer[Tam_buffer];
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
```

If the string in `argv[1]` is more than length `Tam_buffer-1`, you will overwrite the bounds of your array which is undefined behavior.